# Javascript split the HTML attributes and value

Tags: javascript

I have a list of javascript string with HTML tags and want to split the tags.

```
<img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/z38lrml.png" height="60px" />
<section id = "test">
```

I tried to split by double quotes (") but getting only

```
class=", logo"
```

I want to split in the following array

```
[class="logo"], [src="http://i.imgur.com/z38lrml.png"],[height="60px"]
```

and so on for the next line.

Is there anyway to separate?

Thank you

Comment: So, you want an array of objects where each object has a single key value pertaining to each attribute in the element?

Comment: And I do mean **object** because `[class="logo"]` is not a valid array.

Comment: if you really wanna do this from strings.. split on spaces. reduce that to only look for strings that contain '=' ?? otherwise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes

Comment: nvm, splitting on spaces is flawed. but element.attributes is still relevant maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your HTML tag is actually just a string?
In that case, you can use regex:

```js
let html = '<img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/z38lrml.png" height="60px" />';
let attributes = html.match(/[\w-]+="[^"]*"/g);
console.log(attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const attributes = document.querySelector('img').getAttributeNames();
const img = document.querySelector('img');

const output = [...attributes].map((attr) => {
  const val = img.getAttribute(attr);
  return `${attr}" = "${val}`;
});

console.log(output);
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/z38lrml.png" height="60px" />
```

Edit --

If your `html` is a string, use `DOMParser` to convert it into `html`.

```js
const str = `<img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/z38lrml.png" height="60px" />
<section id = "test">`;

const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');

let output = [];
[...dom.body.children].forEach((node) => {
    const attributes = node.getAttributeNames();
    output.push([...attributes].map((attr) => {
        const val = node.getAttribute(attr);
        return `${attr}" = "${val}`;
    }));
})

console.log(output);
```

Comment: @randomSoul, I will have more than 100 lines of HTML tags

Comment: Check your quotes ;) `"class\" = \"logo"`

Comment: @BinitaGyawali _"I will have more than 100 lines..."_ - And the problem is?

Comment: @Andreas - The quotes are perfect when run in the browser.

Comment: Your script outputs `<attributeName>" = "<value>` instead of `<attributeName> = "<value>"`